# Segfault when passing vector of vectors to SSBO using glBufferData

Tags: c++, opengl, memory, segmentation-fault

I am trying to pass a vector of vectors to an SSB0, however I get a segfault when passing it through with `glBufferData`. The structure in C++ is:

```
const uint16_t MAX_NODE_POOLS = 1927;

union Node
{
    uint32_t childDescriptor;
    uint32_t material;
};

struct NodePool
{
    NodePool() : mNodes({0}) {}
    std::array<Node, 8> mNodes;
};

struct Block
{
    Block(): ID(0) {}
    uint16_t ID;
    std::vector<NodePool> mNodePools;
    std::vector<uint16_t> mNodeMasks;
};

class Octree
{
public:
    ...
    void registerSSBO(GLuint &octreeSSBO) const;
    void generate();
    
    [[nodiscard]] inline uint64_t getMem() const { return mBlocks.size() *
    (
            sizeof(uint16_t) +                      // ID
            (sizeof(NodePool)*MAX_NODE_POOLS) +     // NodePools
            (sizeof(uint16_t)*MAX_NODE_POOLS)       // NodeMasks
            ); }
private:
     ...
    std::vector<Block> mBlocks;
};

...

void Octree::Octree::registerSSBO(GLuint &octreeSSBO) const
{
    glGenBuffers(1, &octreeSSBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, octreeSSBO);
    std::cout << getMem() << std::endl;
    glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, getMem(), mBlocks.data(), GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 2, octreeSSBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

I populate the blocks with data, and then I pass into the SSBO like so

```
...
octree.generate();
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

octree.registerSSBO(octreeSSBO);
glBindVertexArray(0);
...
```

In my shader I have the SSBO structured like so

```
#version 430 core
// To use 16 bit integers
#extension GL_NV_gpu_shader5 : enable
#define MAX_NODE_POOLS 1927

struct Node
{
    // Either a child descriptor or material depending on mNodeMasks
    int data;
};

struct NodePool
{
    Node mNodes[8];
};

struct Block
{
    uint16_t ID;
    NodePool mNodePools[MAX_NODE_POOLS];
    uint16_t mNodeMasks[MAX_NODE_POOLS];
};

layout (std430, binding=2) buffer octreeData
{
    Block blocks[];
};
```

Everytime it segfaults on `glBufferData` inside `registerSSBO`

```
glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, getMem(), mBlocks.data(), GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

`getMem()` in this case returns a size of `35773920` bytes, which is the value I expect. Am I calculating it incorrectly? Smaller values like `mBlocks.size()*sizeof(mBlocks)` or `mBlocks.size()*sizeof(Block)` don't cause the application to seg fault (however application doesn't behave as desired)

Running with valgrind prevents the segfault from happening, however gives me 20 warnings `Invalid read of size 16` on the `glBufferData` call, but I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what that might indicate?

In each of the separate warnings it gives me issues like this:

```
Invalid read of size 16
...
Address 0x4cd830b0 is 16 bytes before a block of size 61,664 alloc'd
```

```
Invalid read of size 16
...
Address 0x4cd83080 is 0 bytes after a block of size 57,344 alloc'd
```

```
Invalid read of size 16
...
Address 0x4cd830a0 is 32 bytes before a block of size 61,664 in arena "client"
```

etc

Is this extraneous boiler plate or am I missing something?

Edit:

To show that the vectors are being properly sized I have changed `getMem()` to the following function, and the results are identical

```
inline uint64_t getMem() const 
{
    uint64_t sum = 0;
    for(const auto& b: mBlocks)
    {
        for(const auto& np: b.mNodePools)
            sum += sizeof(np);
        for(const auto& nm: b.mNodeMasks)
            sum += sizeof(nm);
        sum += sizeof(b.ID);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(mBlocks.data())` -- Are you aware of what this value denotes?  It does not tell you the number of bytes that `mBlocks.data()` has.  As a matter of fact, it won't tell you anything important for your program to work.

Comment: Yep I know, I don't use it for anything useful, was just printed there while I was probing out of curiosity. Have removed so as to not distract further

Comment: What you probably want, and is much more relevant, is outputting `mBlocks.size()`.  Printing the `sizeof` a vector does not give you the number of elements.  Second thing is whether the layout of a vector of vectors is compatible with the API you are communicating with.  If not, then you can't use a vector of vectors.

Comment: Your code doesn't show how you resize your vectors. Most probable you never do that, so you access the elements of an empty vector.

Comment: I appreciate you replying but I literally just printed it out of curiosity, I do know the difference, as you can see in my memory calculations. I have been able to send a vector to OpenGL. I'm not sure whether or not I'm capable of sending a vector of vectors, hence the question here.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov I use emplace_back() when placing new elements. I have confirmed that the vectors are properly sized, and not empty vectors.

Comment: You are getting segfaults, and that means that something is wrong with your memory access. As I can see in your code, you are accessing the `data()` member of the `vector` template without checking the size. Try to assert that the precondition is what you expect.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov I have updated the getMem function to ensure the vectors are properly sized, and it produces the same results as original. Please see updated post.

Comment: I'm not sure what the `getMem` should do, but looks like you are trying to return the size of *something*. Multiple instances of this *something* may have different size rather than the sum of the sizes of the components of *something* multiplied to the number of instances.

Comment: I would appreciate if you would read my code before replying. getMem is to calculate the size of the data to send, which is why I use to for glBufferData. The sizeof calls are on pure data structures, which is the size I am looking for. I am iterating through all elements of the vectors, getting their size, and adding that to the total. They will not have different sizes as they are either fixed sized arrays of 8 32 bit integers, or 16 bit integers.

Comment: @0x003 The code doesn't smell right with the `sizeof`'s you are using on types that are not trivially-copyable or are not POD types.  Honestly, it looks odd with those calls of `sizeof`, as I see no value in using sizes of non-trivially-copyable types, unless you are eventually going to use `placement-new` somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> uint16_t ID;
> std::vector<NodePool> mNodePools;
> std::vector<uint16_t> mNodeMasks;
> ...
> glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, getMem(), mBlocks.data(), GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
> ```

You cannot do that. You cannot do a byte-wise copy of most C++ standard library types into OpenGL (or at anything else for that matter). As a general rule, if a type is not [trivially copyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable) (and `vector` is most assuredly *not*), it definitely cannot just be thrown at OpenGL like this (note: this does not mean that you can throw any trivially copyable type at OpenGL. Trivial copyability is necessary but not sufficient).

Your use of `std::array` works (maybe. The C++ standard doesn't guarantee what you think it does about `array`'s layout) because `array<T>` is defined without explicit constructors. As such, it will be trivially copyable to the extent that `T` is trivially copyable.

If you're going to copy C++ objects to GLSL, then the C++ types and layouts *must* match what GLSL defines. `std::vector` in no way matches the layout of any GLSL array. If your GLSL defines an array of X items, then the only C++ type that's definitely going to match that is an actual array of X items (again, necessary but not *sufficient*).

No more, no less.

Comment: Thank you that was the issue. Removing the vectors and replacing them with plain arrays fixed it. Appreciate your help